# Entity Framework - Update complex entities

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, automapper

I'm using EF5.0 (database first) and trying to Update "Company" entity which is a complex type, it contains "Address" entity as navigation property. 
I receive a Company DTO object from UI and I map it, using AutoMapper, to Entity object and call objectContext.Save() for saving.

Problem am facing is, "Company" entity values are getting saved but not the "Address" entity. Below are the each object details-

```
 public class CompanyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
}
```

with AddressDto as -

```
public class AddressDto : IDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

Company Entity (generated by EF - database first)

```
 public partial class tblCompany
{
    public tblCompany()
    {
        this.tblAddresses = new HashSet<tblAddress>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tblAddress> tblAddresses { get; set; } //navigation property
}
```

with Address entity is as follows -

```
  public partial class tblAddress
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public virtual tblCase tblCase { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper mapping configuration for converting from DTO to entity

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyDto, tblCase>()
            .ForMember(x => x.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.Name))
            .AfterMap((s, d) => d.tblAddresses.Add(new tblAddress
            {
                AddressLine1 = s.Address.Street,
                CaseID = s.Id,
                City = s.Address.City,
                PostCode = s.Address.PostCode
            }));



 public void Update(CompanyDto company)
    {
        //TO DO: check if AutoMapper could map address as well.

        var companyDao = Mapper.Map<CompanyDto, tblCase>(company);
        _companyRepository.Update(companyDao);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Sai

Comment: attach the address as an object well.  Your repository will have an ADD or ATTACH method no doubt.  Indeed deciding if the address already exists or not is part of your process. Unless you are happy to have the same address multiple times. Then just add it to context before save.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I want to update the existing address with new one. So by using ADD or ATTACH will it not create a new one instead of updating the existing record.

Comment: attach is used with change.  Context.Entry(poco).State = x; And yes add will try and add. So check if address is already there first if you can. ie have an external address Id or address matching tool. Duplicate addresses are normal otherwise and   Many systems work that way.

Comment: After following you said, I changed the state of address to Modified and then do the Attach for Company objects. Finally when I called Save. It threw an error - "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries." . Looks like When I changed the Addressess object state to Modified, then again when I changed the Customer object state to Modified. Its changing the value of addressess twice so its throwing the error.

Comment: Not sure what is going on.  (if you are using a known Id / key) you may find the AddOrUpdate method nice.   Although it is to be enjoyed with caution.